# Print data in table like single row with multiple column in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

Like the date with would print in column 1 to 30, I need need employee login time and log off time in single days column ...``

I need to print data in table like single row with multiple columns in classic asp

```
<form name="frm_display" method="post">
Welcome: <%=Session("emp_fname")%>
<br>ID: <%=Session("emp_id")%>
<% 
dim con 
dim query 
dim rs2 
set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs2 = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.RECORDSET")
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=swtest.net;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=hr;Data Source=172.16.1.208" 
%>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Month:
            <select name="selmonth">
            <%for i=1 to 12%>
                <%if cint(SelectedMonth)=i then%>
                    <option selected value="<%=i%>">
                    <%=monthname(i)%>
                    </option>
                <%else%>
                    <option value=< %=i%>>
                    <%=monthname(i)%>
                    </option>
                <%end if%>
            <%next%>
            </select>
            Year:
            <select name="selyear">
            <%for i=2000 to year(now)%>
                <option select value=<%=i%>>
                <%=i%>
                </option>
            <%next%>
            </select>
            <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="btn_submit">
        </td>
    </tr> <!-- <-- missing! -->
</table>
</form>
<% 
dim dt 
dt = "1-" & monthname(Request.Form("sel_month")) & "-" & Request.Form("sel_year")
query = "select e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.CompDepart,e.des_name,U.login_time,U.logoff_time,U.login_date " &_
  "from egv_emp_departments e " &_
  "inner join login_mast U on U.emp_id=e.emp_id " &_
  "where month(login_date)='" & request.form("selmonth") &_
  "' AND year(login_date)='" & request.form("selyear") &_
  "' AND e.emp_id='" & Session( "emp_id") & "'"
rs2.open query,con
%>
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr> <!-- added missing tr tag -->
        <td>emp_id</td>
        <td>emp_name</td>
        <td>CompDepart</td>
        <td>des_name</td>
        <%
        dim intDay 
        dim daysInMonth 
        dim strMonth 
        dim stryear 
        intDay=1 
        strMonth = request("selmonth") 
        stryear = request("selyear") 
        If strMonth <> "" Then 
            If stryear <> "" Then 
                Select Case strMonth 
                    Case 1,3,5,7,8, 10,12 daysInMonth = 31 
                    Case 4, 6, 9, 11 daysInMonth = 30 
                    Case 2
                        if stryear mod 4 = 0 Then 
                            If stryear mod 100 = 0 AND stryear mod 400 <> 0 Then 
                                daysInMonth = 28 
                            Else 
                                daysInMonth = 29 
                            End if 
                        Else 
                            daysInMonth=28 
                        End if 
                End Select 
                Do While intDay <= daysInMonth 
                    Response.Write "<td>" & intDay & "</td>"
                    intDay = intDay + 1 
                Loop 
            Else 
            End if 
        End if 

        for each x in rs2.fields ' <-- fixed typo "feilds"
            response.write "<th>" & x.name & "<th>"
        next
        %>
    </tr> <!-- added missing /tr tag -->
<%do until rs2.EOF %>
    <tr>
    <%for each x in rs2.Fields%>
        <td>
        <%Response.Write(x.value)%>
        </td>
    <% next %>
    <% rs2.MoveNext %>
    </tr>
<%loop 
rs2.close 
con.close %>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? 2 extra columns (login time and logoff time) in an existing row?

Comment: Yes.... in the day sequence order i need to print  login in and log off time in each and every column in the day

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought you wanted what's called a "PivotTable" in Excel, but then I noticed that you're filtering to a single employee. It's still not clear to me what you mean by "single days column" vs. "like single row with multiple column", but I assume you mean something like:

```
Employee: Smith, John
ID: 123456
Month: March
—————————————————
Day  | In  |  Out
  1  |  8  |   5
  2  |  8  |   5
  3  |  -  |   -
  4  |  9  |   5
...  | ... |  ...
 30  |  9  |   4
 31  |  8  |   4
—————————————————
```

In other words, your problem is that there might be days with no data, but you still want to print those rows. The simplest way to handle that is probably a temp table with the numbers 1 through 31 in it, which you then use in an outer join with the rest of your query. If you can't do that (e.g. you're not allowed to create temp tables - don't laugh, it happens), then you can do it in code instead.

The easiest way to do it in code is to put the values from the database into an array, but not by using GetRows. Instead, put each day's value into the corresponding row of the array.

```
dim listdays(31,1)
...
Do Until rs2.EOF
    dt = Day(rs2("login_date"))
    listdays(dt,0) = rs2("login_time")
    listdays(dt,1) = rs2("logoff_time")
    rs2.Movenext
Loop
```

<sub><sup>(I'll pause while the purists finish having conniptions. Trust me, any performance hit from using `Movenext` on a recordset that contains, at most, 31 rows, is going to be so infinitesimal as to be nonexistent.)</sup></sub>

Then you simply write out the contents of the array.

```
Response.Write "<table><tr><th>Day</th><th>Login</th><th>Logoff</th></tr>"
For i = 1 to DaysInMonth
    Response.Write "<tr>"
    Response.Write "<th>" & i & "</th>"
    Response.Write "<td>" & listdays(i,0) & "</td>"
    Response.Write "<td>" & listdays(i,1) & "</td>"
    Response.Write "</tr>"
Next
Response.Write "</table>"
```

Comment: what you told is correct , but i need in column header with single row data.

Comment: Yes.... in the day sequence order i need to print login in and log off time in each and every column in the day

Comment: @xavier: unfortunately, I don't understand what you're trying to say. Do you mean you want the table to go the other way, i.e. a column for each day, then a row for the logins and a second row for the logoffs?